# Convert text string to binary ASCII in an Arduino sketch

Tags: binary, arduino, ascii

I am writing a sketch for Arduino that aims to convert a text string into binary 7-bit or 8-bit ASCII. For example, "Hello World" would become this 8-bit ASCII binary stream:

0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000111011101101111011100100110110001100100

As you can see, this is standard 7-bit ASCII padded with zeros to make it 8-bit ASCII. I don't mind which bit length I use as long as it's consistent once I've started. I've spent a couple of hours trying to work out a method to achieve that to no avail. The closest I have is something like this:

```
char text[] = "Hello world";
```

which when printed to the monitor like this:

```
Serial.println(text[0], BIN);
```

Gives me 1001000. However, this isn't at all padded (so "0" would simply be 0, not 0000000) and obviously this doesn't provide me with anything to work with, just something to look at! Does anyone have any advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a starting point:

```
char inputChar = 'H';

// This will 'output' the binary representation of 'inputChar' as 8 characters of '1's and '0's, MSB first.
for ( uint8_t bitMask = 128; bitMask != 0; bitMask = bitMask >> 1 ) {
  if ( inputChar & bitMask ) {
    output('1');
  } else {
    output('0');
  }
}
```